# Json file cant be edited

Tags: python, json

I want to append the brightness 0 to all lamps in list to a empty json file.

```
def first_start(lamps:list):
    for lamp in lamps:
        dict = {"light": {lamp: {"brightness": 0}}}
        with open("data.json", "r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            data.update(dict)
        print(dict)
        with open("data.json", 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)
```

Everytime I run this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brend\PycharmProjects\Hue_Control\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    first_start(lamps)
  File "C:\Users\brend\PycharmProjects\Hue_Control\main.py", line 16, in first_start
    data = json.load(file)
  File "C:\Users\brend\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\brend\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\brend\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\brend\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Could somebody please help me, what im doing wrong?
Thank you :)

Comment: Aside: It's a bad idea to name a dict `dict`; doing so means you can no longer refer to the `dict` type by its name in the context where that name is in force.

Comment: Anyhow -- you said your starting file is empty, right? You can't load a completely empty file as JSON. To be a valid JSON file, there has to be _some_ JSON object in it, even if it's just `{}` or `[]`. So you should probably just check if the file is originally empty and skip trying to load it if it is.

Comment: Hmm..., you pretend to have a valid Json file but can only open an empty file... Likely the current working directly is not what you expect. Control it with `print(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, it is working now :)

Comment: Post a sample of what `data.json` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an empty `json` file. If you have an empty file, then its not a `json` file.

You could ignore all the errors and assume that the file should contain `"{}"` and carry on:

```py
def first_start(lamps:list):
    for lamp in lamps:
        upd = {"light": {lamp: {"brightness": 0}}}
        data = {}  # Empty dict just in case

        try:
            with open("data.json", "r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
        except Exception:
            print('Ignore errors with data.json')
        data.update(upd)

        with open("data.json", 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)
```